# Why .hasClass function isnt working?

Tags: javascript, css

So My code do when i click on name(class ='frnd'), then in result open one window and it is drag-able but when i again click on (class =frnd) then their open again new windows, for example if i click on Simon there popup new windows and after one click it is drag-able and than once more i click on name(class ='frnd' (Simon)) its popup one more window again. Problem: I dont want that if the window is already open, it wont open again same window Simon.

For avoid this problem i was trying this code in js

```
if(!($("#windows").hasClass('.5647383'+id))){
                $html = '<div class="mwindow "><div class="hwindow 5647383'+id+'">'+usr+'<span class="cls">x</span></div><div class="msgbody '+id+'"><div id="mstd"class= umsg'+id+'></div><div id="tarea"><form method="post"><textarea class="ctarea" name="'+id+'"></textarea></form></div></div></div>';
                $('#windows').append($html);
        }
```

I don't know  why isnt working thiscondition `if($("#windows").hasClass('.5647383'+id))`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.frnd').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var usr=$(this).text();
        var exst = document.getElementsByClassName('.5647383'+id); 
        if($("#windows").hasClass('.5647383'+id)){
            $html = '<div class="mwindow "><div class="hwindow 5647383'+id+'">'+usr+'<span class="cls">x</span></div><div class="msgbody '+id+'"><div id="mstd"class= umsg'+id+'></div><div id="tarea"><form method="post"><textarea class="ctarea" name="'+id+'"></textarea></form></div></div></div>';
            $('#windows').append($html);
    }
    });

    $('#windows').on('click','.cls', function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });

    $(function(){ 
        $('.frnd').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#windows').on('click','.'+id,function(){
        $(this).parent().draggable({
          handle: ".hwindow",
          containment:"body"
        });
      });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #999;
  height: 700px;
  }
.frnd {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #9B59B6;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 4px solid #3498DB;
  color: #F1C40F;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  }
.mwindow {
  position: fixed;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 5px solid #16a085;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.mwindow:hover {
  z-index: 9999;
  }
.hwindow {
  width: 210px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #FF4500;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.cls {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
.msgbody {
  position: relative;
  height: 185px;
  background-color: #FF4500;
  //z-index:9999;
  }
.ctarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  top: 133px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 40px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border: none;
  border-top: 2px solid #ff0000;
  }
#mstd {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  height: 133px;
  background-color: #bb4500;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<li id="7" class="frnd">Maxi</li>
  <li id="8" class="frnd">John</li>
  <li id="9" class="frnd">Henry</li>
  <li id="10" class="frnd">Max</li>
  <li id="11" class="frnd">Simon</li>
<div id="windows"></div>
```

Comment: `'.' + id` should be `'#' + id`.

Comment: i am trying to do  it in snippet but its cant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements by their ID attribute are selected using the hashmark symbol, so

`'.' + id` should be `'#' + id`.

The dot symbol (.) selects elements by their class name.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdaXgX

**EDIT**

You had a number of other problems, look at the reviewed code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdwaWx

Comment: There were other problems, check my update and new Codepen. Compare it with the first one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean is the same, but in the 2nd Codepan after you click a name (top right), a bigger box appears with the same name (top left) and it is draggable by its titlebar (the bright red bar on the top).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `hasClass()` doesn’t use a period prefix for classes — that’s *selector* syntax. So:

- `var hwindow_div = $('.5647383'+id)` will find your .hwindow div,
- `hwindow_div.hasClass('5647383'+id)` checks whether it has the class.

[A simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/70Lbauca/).

PS. while it’s a separate problem, @marekful is correct about the `#id` syntax.

Comment: Here Check my clip. i dont want that two windows of same user

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand what you mean… change your check to `if($("#windows").hasClass('5647383'+id))` and it should work (to see if `#windows` has that class, at least).

Comment: oo shi t i forgot  to write down link in frist comment. sorry

Comment: I see… `hasClass()` checks the element it’s run against, but you want to check its descendents. Try `if($("#windows").find('.5647383'+id).length){`.

Comment: lol  work but create more problems here onemore clip https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B93vyI8naA3OOU1NSWo5SlgyeUU/edit

Comment: To check that `#windows` does *not* have that descendant, use `if(!$("#windows").find('.5647383'+id).length){`.